# Not getting correct class value with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, closest

I'm working on a project where I'm displaying a list of images. At each image there is the possibility to the delete the item and to edit.

When a user clicks on "Edit" a modal has to show up with the corresponding data. Now my problem is to get the title and the description of the selected item.

I have searched before on this problem and I know that I have to use the jQuery function "closest" but I haven't been able to get it working.

```
var thisTitle = $(this).closest(".photo").closest(".item_title").text();
```

Here you can find my jsFiddle: [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/ddxsmtzq/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `closest` then correct selector would be:

```
var thisTitle = $(this).closest(".photo-wrapper").find(".item_title").text();
```

First you need to find closest parent container with class `photo-wrapper` (not `photo`) and *within* this container you search for `.item_title`.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ddxsmtzq/2/